# Modify Apollo React function to use parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo

I'm currently using this function in React:

```
function GQLFunc() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GQLTAGS);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  if (data) return <WrappedApp data={data.tag} />;
}
```

I want to make this function re-usable with a parameter so tried:

```
function GQLFunc(callingApp) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GQLTAGS);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  if (data) return <callingApp data={data.tag} />;
}
```

Then called it here:

```
<GQLFunc callingApp={WrappedApp} />
```

What am I doing wrong here?  I'd also like to add a parameter for `data = data.tag`

Comment: component names are uppercased

Comment: `function GQLFunc(props) { let Component = props.callingApp .... return <Component data....`

Comment: @xadm Is it possible to show updated code as answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use uppercased name of rendered component, f.e.:

```
function GQLFunc(props) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GQLTAGS);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  let CallingApp = props.callingApp;
  if (data) return <CallingApp data={data.tag} />;
}
```